# Visibility of <li> does not carry over when redirected to homepage after successful firebase login (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase-authentication

I have just started learning about html,JS and CSS because of a school project. I am trying to implement a firebase authentication feature in my project but there seems to be a problem. After a successful login, I am trying to change the visibility of #login to hidden and #logout to visible. It works only for the login.html and not when it is redirected back to homepage after successful login. What am I missing out on?

Javascript

```
// Authentication 
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      document.getElementById("login").style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("logout").style.visibility = "visible";
      console.log("Should have changed");
    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    document.getElementById("logout").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("login").style.visibility = "visible";

  }
});

function login() {

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).then(function (user) {
    document.getElementById("login").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("logout").style.visibility = "visible";
    location.href="/";
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });
```

Index.html

```
<!-- side nav -->
    <ul id="side-menu" class="sidenav side-menu">
        <li><a class="subheader">CookHealthySG</a></li>
        <li><a href="/" class="waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages/search.html" class="waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">search</i>Search</a></li>

        <li><a href="/pages/about.html" class="waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">info</i>About</a></li>
        <li>
            <div class="divider"></div>
        </li>
        <li id="login"><a href="/pages/login.html" class="waves-effect"><i
                    class="material-icons">vpn_key</i>Login</a></li>
        <li id="logout"><a class="waves-effect" onclick="logout()"><i class="material-icons">vpn_key</i>Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

login.html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CookHealthySG</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" href="/css/authentication.css.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <!-- top nav -->
        <nav class="green z-depth-0">
                <div class="nav-wrapper container">
                        <a class="brand-logo center"
                                style="font-family:courier,arial,helvetica;">Login</span></a>
                        <span class="left white-text text-darken-1">
                                <i class="large material-icons sidenav-trigger" data-target="side-menu">menu</i>
                        </span>
                </div>

        </nav>
        <!-- side nav -->
        <ul id="side-menu" class="sidenav side-menu">
                <li><a class="subheader">CookHealthySG</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" class="waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/pages/search.html" class="waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">search</i>Search</a></li>

                <li><a href="/pages/about.html" class="waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">info</i>About</a></li>
                <li>
                        <div class="divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li id="login"><a href="/pages/login.html" class="waves-effect"><i
                                        class="material-icons">vpn_key</i>Login</a></li>
                <li id="logout"><a class="waves-effect" onclick="logout()"><i class="material-icons">vpn_key</i>Logout</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
                <!-- Login -->
                <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
                        <input  class="input100" type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field"
                                pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2, 4}$" />
                        <input  class="input100" type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password_field" minlength="8" required />

                        <button class ="loginBtn" onclick="login()">Login</button>
                </div>

        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
        <script>
                // Initialize Firebase
                var config = {
                        apiKey: "AIzaSyDtR5nwOSAex9szmciR064wY9DKCKyCI0k",
                        authDomain: "firestore-example-projec-c3939.firebaseapp.com",
                        databaseURL: "https://firestore-example-projec-c3939.firebaseio.com",
                        projectId: "firestore-example-projec-c3939",
                        storageBucket: "firestore-example-projec-c3939.appspot.com",
                        messagingSenderId: "368951762374",
                        appId: "1:368951762374:web:59ad5d37d7170e07a9a6c7"
                };
                firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>
        <script src="/js/ui.js "></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Button IDs should be unique within the documents.

`getElementById` must return the first element with the given ID, making the behavior not undefined in the case of duplicate IDs.

Comment: ok, i have changed the id to login and logout but the visibility does not seem to work as intended. Right now, after the initial login, #login is still visible and the #logout is hidden. Only when I click on #login and get directed to login.html that #login becomes hidden and #logout visible